# How to show the result on Tooltip while running java file - IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

In this [video](https://youtu.be/oRcOiGWK9Ts?t=1640), Venkat Subramaniam is running simple java file and he is able to see the result on screen as the given below image. Does anybody know which tool he is using ?

[image]

Comment: Off-topic for SO, but I believe [that's **TextMate**](https://www.agilelearner.com/?q=textmate).

Comment: https://macromates.com/

Answer (score 0):

Its actually a wonderful feature, but unfortunately this only work for Textmate.

Here you could find how to set it up for Textmate: https://www.ivonet.nl/2017/11/07/textmate-get-run-output-as-tooltip/

For IntelliJ IDEA there no such thing. But, a one guy has tried to do it in InteliJ Idea with a [plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8543-tooltiprunner) which is available at https://github.com/jcraane/intellij-tooltip-runner. But, it is outdated and not working in recent releases.